# Marketing Cloud - different domain for sending email versus landing pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-domain, sfmc-business-unit, sender-authentication-package

I am configuring SAP so that a customer can have the custom domain in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

However, he wants to use two different domains: one for sending e-mails and the other for Landing Pages (both in a single business unit).

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? If so, is it possible to request two domains on the SAP form? Or is it possible to have but only for different business units?

Comment: I have added more details to my answer, remember to accept it, if it has been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple SAPs on a single Business Unit. But you can add multiple Private Domains, which can be used both as an additional sender domain, as well as a domain for your Cloud Pages.

For sending emails, SAP and Private Domain are equally good. They both offer the same degree of authentication (SPF/DKIM/DMARC), the few differences are:

1. There can be only a single SAP on a Business Unit
2. There can be multiple Private Domains on a Business Unit
3. Only SAP provides link branding of links and images within emails

When it comes to Cloud Pages, both SAP and Private domain can provide branding of your Cloud Page URLs.

You should raise a support case to have your Private Domain configured. It normally requires your DNS records, for the subdomain you want to use, to be delegated. It also requires, that you have a Private Domain available in your contract.